# How to show disclosure indicator while cells are in edit mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView that can be edited. I am displaying cells as such:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    STWatchList *mySTWatchList;
    mySTWatchList = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = mySTWatchList.watchListName;

    return cell;
}
```

When the user is editing, I would like to show the disclosure indicator. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    else
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
```